# how to specify random_state in LDA model for topic modelling

Tags: python, text, model, cpu-word

I read the gensim LDA model documentation about random_state which states that:

```
random_state ({np.random.RandomState, int}, optional)
```

– Either a randomState object or a seed to generate one. Useful for reproducibility.

I have been tring put random_state=42 or

```
random_seed=42
state=np.random.RandomState(random_seed)
state.randn(1)
random_state=state.randn(1)
```

which did not work. Can anyone suggest what should i do

model=ldaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=num_topics, random_state=None)

I tied to use it without random_state the function it works but with random_state i got error message saying LDA model is not defined

def compute_coherence_values(dictionary, corpus, texts, limit, random_state, start=2, 
 step=3):

```
coherence_values = []
model_list = []
for num_topics in range(start, limit, step):
    #model=LdaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=num_topics)
    model=ldaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=num_topics, 
                                                  random_state)
    model_list.append(model)
    coherencemodel = CoherenceModel(model=model, texts=texts, dictionary=dictionary, coherence='c_v')
    coherence_values.append(coherencemodel.get_coherence())

return model_list, coherence_values
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The mistake in your code is in here:

```
 model=ldaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=num_topics, 
                                                  random_state)
```

You can't just pass the variable `random_state` without specifying the label. Just passing the variable to the method with an int number means nothing to the `ldaModel` method, since the method does not take positional parameter. The method takes named parameters. So it should be like this:

```
model=ldaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=num_topics, 
                                                  random_state = random_state)
```

I have an implementation of the LDA that uses `LatentDirichletAllocation` from `sklearn.decomposition`, and for the `random_state` it takes an integer. Here is an example:

```
lda_model = LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=10,        
                                  max_iter=10,               
                                  learning_method='online',   
                                  random_state=100,          
                                  batch_size=128,            
                                  evaluate_every = -1,       
                                  n_jobs = -1 )
```

[Here is a good tutorial](https://medium.com/@yanlinc/how-to-build-a-lda-topic-model-using-from-text-601cdcbfd3a6) on how to implement and LDA

Comment: Hi Anna, yes if I specify the random_state in like you did it works. it seems something wrong when I define it in the function.  Any idea , i just updated the post. Thanks

Comment: I was trying modify the function from this [ link ] (https://datascienceplus.com/evaluation-of-topic-modeling-topic-coherence/)

Comment: You can’t just pass the random_state variable, you have to specify the parameter name and the value of it. Let me update my comment

Comment: i did try to define the function this way :    def compute_coherence_values(dictionary, corpus, texts, limit, random_state=100, start=2, step=3):

Comment: and in the function like you suggested:        model=ldaModel(corpus=corpus, id2word=dictionary, num_topics=num_topics,                                              random_state = random_state)

Comment: The labeling is only for the LdaModel, not your own function that you are defining. your function should be like this `def compute_coherence_values(dictionary, corpus, texts, limit, random_state, start, step)`

Comment: I think start=2 and step=3 just provide the default value.   I did try your suggestions to remove the default value.  It still shows error LDA model is not defined. it is really odd for me. it should work.