# Which parameters within the sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation will improve the performance of the Topic Modelling?

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, nlp, topic-modeling

I am currently trying to optimise a LDA model I am doing on some text data. Beyond changing the number of topics, what other parameters will significantly improve the model?

This is my current code which I copied from another [stackoverflow Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61373994/how-to-specify-random-state-in-lda-model-for-topic-modelling):

```
LatentDirichletAllocation(n_components=10,        
                                  max_iter=10,               
                                  learning_method='online',   
                                  random_state=100,          
                                  batch_size=128,            
                                  evaluate_every = -1,       
                                  n_jobs = -1 )
```

I am having trouble understanding what these different parameters actually do. The [sklearn explanation from the official site lacks detail](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.decomposition.LatentDirichletAllocation.html) and every [medium article](https://medium.com/@yanlinc/how-to-build-a-lda-topic-model-using-from-text-601cdcbfd3a6) skims over what these parameters do. Is there a source that breaks down these in plain english?:

- learning_method
- evaluate _every
- n_jobs = -1
- learning_offset=10.0,
- ax_doc_update_iter=100
- max_iter=10,
- n_jobs=None,
- random_state=42,
- topic_word_prior=None

I'm aware I don't have a statistics background but I want to understand the code I'm implementing a bit more. Thanks

Comment: What is the definition of topic modelling improvement?

Comment: In this case, I'm topic modelling a subreddit post on video games so being able to identify the sub-topics within the thread. An ideal scenario for improvement would have less overlap between topics - A lot of the topics have the same keywords in each topic.